libvirt iptables forwarding, forwarding is not working, although it was before. What else can i check?
I'm on ubuntu 20 using libvirt to host an ubuntu 20 vm. The port forwarding has suddenly stopped working. Internet and all other functions still work as expected.
I've tried resetting virbr0 and tried flushing the iptables, having the default recreated by libivrt. Restarted the host and guest too. Is there anything obviously wrong here / any other config i should look into?
Some common outputs ive seen people ask for/ excluding some common problems:
Output of telnet 192.168.122.104 5001 
Trying 192.168.122.104...
Connected to 192.168.122.104.
Escape character is '^]'.

Yes, program is listening on guest port.
Output of sudo netstat -plant
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 192.168.122.1:53        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      553220/dnsmasq      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1322/systemd-resolv 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1557/sshd: /usr/sbi 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5900          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      563376/qemu-system- 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      184233/cupsd        
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.22:43298      165.254.239.131:443     ESTABLISHED 1572/vncserver-x11- 

Nope, program doesnt get forwarded to host port.
The output of sudo iptables -L -n -t nat -v
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 3127 packets, 364K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5001 to:192.168.122.104:5001
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5000 to:192.168.122.104:5000

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 306 packets, 37886 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 984 packets, 96927 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 933 packets, 86727 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 2168  211K LIBVIRT_PRT  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain LIBVIRT_PRT (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    9  1090 RETURN     all  --  *      *       192.168.122.0/24     224.0.0.0/24        
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       192.168.122.0/24     255.255.255.255     
 1085 65100 MASQUERADE  tcp  --  *      *       192.168.122.0/24    !192.168.122.0/24     masq ports: 1024-65535
  146 59104 MASQUERADE  udp  --  *      *       192.168.122.0/24    !192.168.122.0/24     masq ports: 1024-65535
    0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      *       192.168.122.0/24    !192.168.122.0/24    

I had ufw turned on, even when it was working. Disabling it did not change anything.

I am assuming you want localhost to redirect to port 5001 at ip 192.168.122.104
I see you have a DNAT rule for dpt 5001 to be forward to 192.168.122.104:5001 Prerouting.
Prerouting is the keyword here.  By default linux will not route to localnet.  Therefore it will never trigger the Prerouting rule.
To confirm run (remove virbr0 with the name of the interface if it is different to virbr0):
sysctl net.ipv4.conf.virbr0.route_localnet
if it is currently set to 0, then you need to change it by running:
sysctl net.ipv4.conf.virbr0.route_localnet=1
if you want to enable it for all interfaces then:
sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.route_localnet=1
That should fix the problem, if not, then I would suggesting checking you have all the modules needed for iptables to do nat installed and active.

I dont necessarily need the port available in localhost. I removed the localhost telnet output to prevent misunderstanding. More importantly the port should be visible in netstat, but isnt.
Thank you for pointing out that using localhost would require additional steps.

@benjamin users are not able to upvote their own posts.  Your last statement is argumentative and has a harrassing tone.

@benjamin the port will show in netstat inside the vm not the host, port 5001 of the vm is listening, and therefore if you open a shell in the vm, and did netstat it will show that it is open.  On the host, it will not show it is open, because it is not, what happens, is iptables redirects the packet before it is sent to the kernel to process.  Therefore the host will not have a port in listening, and you wont see it in netstat
